# Direct Airside Transit Visa Questions

Tags: visas, uk, transit-visas, standard-visitor-visas, datv

I'm applying for a direct airside UK transit visa and these are my questions:

1. I run an online shop please how do I answer the question

   - What is your job?
2. Please how do I answer this question since I'm only transiting UK:

   - How much do you personally plan to spend on your visit to the UK?
3. How much do you earn?

   - Is this before or after expenses such as tax?

Comment: _Very_ general answers for a _very_ vague question: 1) Business owner, 2) £20 (figure you'll buy lunch at the airport), 3) Gross income (before taxes). Of course, without more details, it's hard to provide better answers than that.

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you

Comment: The comment above is pretty much an answer, it could be posted as such.

Comment: @André yes! Thanks a lot